# Is the use of "siunitx" recommended for dimensionless numbers for any reason?

Tags: siunitx

My question is about possible advantages of writing

```
$\mbox{\textit{Re}}=\SI{0.137}{}$
```

instead of

```
$\mbox{\textit{Re}}=0.137$
```

Is there any?

Comment: you don't need \mbox in either case you could just use `\textit` or better, `\mathit`

Comment: For this purpose, siunitx has `\num{<number>}` macro so you don't need to skip the unit.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I was in fact looking for the reasons. For example, I found that `\SI{0,137}{}` or `\num{0,137}` prints as 0.137 instead of 0,137.

Comment: [At least when using Spanish `babel` and `\decimalpoint`]. One disadvantage, for me, of using `\num` is that you won't find every number in your code by just searching "\SI".

Comment: You should not be using `\SI` if you just want a number: they are semantically different.

Comment: @Andrestand, you can load the package with the `decimalsymbol` option, if you are writting in spanish and you don't want to use the international format. Just load `\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}`

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral, thanks, although I use in fact point, despite Spanish `babel` for some reason switches it to comma.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\num` command is provided primarily to allow consistent number formatting with the first argument to `\SI`. Thus whether you want to use `\num` is primarily about whether you need that consistent formatting. For example, `\num` will do things like turn `,` into `.` (as standard) to produce normal scientific output even if the input is localised. It will also turn `1.2e3` into `1.2 \times 10^{3}` and so forth.

Of course, if you choose to turn off the number parser in `siunitx` then the format of numbers is the same between `$1.23$` and `\num{1.23}`. (Indeed, while people mainly ask about number formatting the real core point of `siunitx` is not that but the idea of consistent application of *units*.)